# How to precisely identify missing template exceptions during XSLT compilation?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt

I am dealing with a large set of legacy XSLT templates, many of which are published under a license that makes it difficult for me to change their contents.

Almost all of these were tested with an XSLT engine that is much more lenient than .NET's XslCompiledTransform.  However, I need to use the XslCompiledTransform for my purposes.

I have working code here that handles the error (converting the compilation error into a runtime error), but I don't like the mechanism I was using to detect the error (Regex).

Is there a way to detect this specific error in a more generic way?

```cs
var doc = XDocument.Load(path, LoadOptions.SetBaseUri);

while (true)
{
    try
    {
        using (var reader = doc.CreateReader())
        {
            var transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
            transform.Load(reader);
            this.transform = transform;
            break;
        }
    }
    catch (XsltException ex)
    {
        // TODO: I need to find a future-proof and locale-proof mechanism to detect this error.
        var messageMatch = Regex.Match(ex.Message, "The named template '(?<name>[_A-Za-z0-9]+)' does not exist.");
        if (messageMatch.Success)
        {
            // Add a runtime termination, rather than failing the transform compilation.
            doc.Root.Add(
                new XElement(
                    xsl + "template",
                    new XAttribute("name", messageMatch.Groups["name"].Value),
                    new XElement(
                        xsl + "message",
                        new XAttribute("terminate", "yes"),
                        ex.ToString())));
            continue;
        }

        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does that exception have any other properties like an error code? Have you considered using an XSLT 2 or 3 processor which might give an error code defined in the XSLT spec (e.g. `XTSE0650`)? Saxon 10 does that, for instance: https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/StaticError.html#ErrorCode

Comment: Some people have also tried to use XSLT to write linter e.g. https://github.com/greystate/XSLT-Lint/blob/master/XSLTLint.xslt that can detect such problems.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I didn't see anything in the `Data` dictionary.

Comment: You are not detecting the error, you are extracting the name from a string and Regex is a good method for extracting the name.

Comment: I wonder whether the `HResult` property at least has a distinct error code to allow you to identify that particular problem, `string.Format("{0:x8}", ex.HResult)` gives `80131942` in a quick test so I would check whether that is some unique code for the error that a template is attempted to be called for which no named template exists.